# Comparing stack data structure c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have the following program.What is the best , and most efficient way to check if the two stacks are equal by the values they contain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct StackNode
{
    int data;
     StackNode* next;
};

 StackNode* newNode(int data)
{
     StackNode* stackNode = new StackNode[sizeof(StackNode)];

    stackNode->data = data;
    stackNode->next = NULL;
    return stackNode;
}

int isEmpty( StackNode *root)
{
    return !root;
}

void push( StackNode** root, int data)
{
     StackNode* stackNode = newNode(data);
    stackNode->next = *root;
    *root = stackNode;

}

int pop( StackNode** root)
{
    if (isEmpty(*root))
        return INT_MIN;
     StackNode* temp = *root;
    *root = (*root)->next;
    int popped = temp->data;
    free(temp);

    return popped;
}

int peek(StackNode* root)
{
    if (isEmpty(root))
        return INT_MIN;
    return root->data;
}

bool AreEqual(StackNode** lhs, StackNode** rhs)
{
   ////// ?
}

int main()
{
    StackNode* root = NULL;
    StackNode * r2 = NULL;
    push(&root, 10);
    push(&root, 20);
    push(&root, 30);


    push(&r2, 123);
    push(&r2, 1231213);

    AreEqual(&root, &r2);
}
```

if the stacks contains equivalent numbers but in different order , then the method should return true .. I would be very thankful if you could give me some directions for that task.Thanks in advice.

Comment: What you've asked for is called operator abuse.  Stacks are the same if each item in the stack is the same; and order matters.  By saying you're happy to accept elements out of order; this isn't a stack comparison any more.  What you're looking for is a thing called a 'set'

Comment: Ok then if i want to compare each element , what's the best way ?

Comment: @UKMonkey: _"By saying you're happy to accept elements out of order; this isn't a stack comparison any more."_ It's still a comparison, it's just not an equivalence comparison.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... true.  I like adding my own words in my head to the question; it often makes the question easier ;)

Comment: @UKMonkey: But then it's not the same question 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How often do people ask the question they really mean anyway? :P

Comment: @UKMonkey: Is that really what you meant to ask?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you always answer a question with a question?

Comment: @UKMonkey: How do you feel about that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit do you do counseling often, you seem well practiced?

Comment: @UKMonkey: I am a licensed Stack Exchange psychiatrist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can imagine there's a significant need of them here - there's plenty of nutters around!

Comment: @UKMonkey: It does keep me busy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It could drive me to nuts if I wasn't already a monkey.

Comment: @UKMonkey: Yo dawg, I put nuts in your monkey so you can monkey while you monkey.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit   *UKMonkey breaks* I'm not a dog :(  but ... I ... you ...

Answer (score 2):

Considering

> if the stacks contains equivalent numbers but in different order , then the method should return true

I think the optimal solution would be via sort and compare.

Extract the data from each stack

```
k1 = {data of lhs}     -> O(n)
k2 = {data of rhs}     -> O(n)
```

Sort the two arrays

```
k1_sorted = sort(k1)   -> O(n log(n))
k2_sorted = sort(k2)   -> O(n log(n))
```

Now you can compare the two sorted arrays in O(n). Keep in mind the possible repeated numbers in k1_sorted and k2_sorted.

Comment: I can't think of a better way to do it, offhand, given the likely constraints. I think you could take a "count equivalence" method using a map of _value_ ⇨ _(int,int)_, then walk through each stack incrementing the integers (LHS when found in stack 1, RHS when found in stack 2), and finally examine each pair and compare all integer values for equality. But to do that you have to treat the stack as not a stack by accessing its underlying datastore, which may or may not be permitted.

Comment: Even if OP can't edit the stacks; then this is still the solution I think; but a copy must be made first.  Good answer though

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that would allow you to bail when your 'not matched items' list is larger than the remaining size to process... best case is you only have to process half the list.  Me Likey.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the sort method, you could take a counting approach:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


/**
 * Returns true iff the two vectors contain the same elements
 * (including number of duplicates) in any order.
 *  
 * Alternatively std::sort both vectors and just compare them
 * for equality, which may or may not be faster.
 */
bool sortOfEquivalent(const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs)
{
    std::map<int, std::pair<int,int>> accumulator;

    for (const auto x : lhs) {
        accumulator[x].first++;
    }

    for (const auto x : rhs) {
        accumulator[x].second++;

        if (accumulator[x].second > accumulator[x].first) {
            // Can bail early here; the RHS already has
            // more x's than the LHS does
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (const auto& y : accumulator) {
        if (y.second.first != y.second.second)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> lhs{3,5,5,7,1};
    std::vector<int> rhs{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    std::cout << sortOfEquivalent(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Depending on your data, this may or may not be faster than the sorting method. It also may or may not take less storage than the sorting method.

Also in reality you'd probably take a reference to `accumulator[x]` in that second loop rather than looking up the element three times.

However, you can only apply this solution to your situation if you treat your stack as not-a-stack, i.e. using its underlying data store (forward iteration is required). This may or may not be permitted.

Answer (score -1):

On the outside your functions handle a stack, but the actual structure you implement the stack in is a simple linked list.

And comparing two linked lists is done by comparing each element one by one, stopping when either list runs out or you find a difference in the elements.

Comment: `if the stacks contains equivalent numbers but in different order , then the method should return true`  You missed this part of the question

Comment: @UKMonkey Yes I did, and as you say it's then no longer a comparison of the stacks.